# Ubunto .rar file is downloading instead of .iso

Tags: windows, iso, rar

I am trying to download Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Desktop) for Virtual box to run it on windows, but .rar file is downloading instead of .iso file 
I can not find any solution for this. Can someone kindly helo me with this

Comment: Here directlink for 64bit desktop iso. https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: That's strange, can we see that link?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove any programs that extract archives (eg. WinRAR,7Zip, etc.) on your Windows PC
2. Download the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop image. Click [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso) for a direct download link (for 64bit computers)
3. You should now have a Ubuntu 20.04 .iso disk image file